# JQuery-UI Tabs for winstore apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm currently building an app using JS+HTML for windows store

This is the jSFiddle I tried (copied from the example given from the jquery-ui site)

http://jsfiddle.net/youkai/E4cCy/3/

However when I implemented it into visual studio project, it doesn't show up like in the jsfiddle (tabbed). it showed up like a list like this:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/713/8suv.png

Any idea why that happened? I'm just starting to learn about jquery, so I don't really know what's wrong, since I also just copied it from the official example....

This is how i write the code in jsfiddle into a visual studio project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test2</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- test2 references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        // fix the classes
        $(".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav, .tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav > *")
          .removeClass("ui-corner-all ui-corner-top")
          .addClass("ui-corner-bottom");

        // move the nav to the bottom
        $(".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav").appendTo(".tabs-bottom");
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-spacer"></div>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you might be missing the jQuery UI css that will style the tabs appearance.

Comment: oh you're right!! i never thought i'd need the css because it doesn't installed with the jquery-ui (and since in jsfiddle i do not need to write a reference to it)
Thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: glad I could help. I'll put it as a formal answer so you can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the jQuery UI CSS. You'll need that in order to style the tabs with the proper appearance.